# How to have tree-top without branch in Git Extensions (or git, if no GUI-way to accomplish it)?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am here:

[image: initial]

I want to go back to "**test works**", but if I click "`reset current branch to here`" over the "**test works**" commit, no matter what I choose (Soft/Mixed/Hard), it removes (deletes, erases) the "**not sure about this direction...**" commit. I don't want to delete it, as I may decide to get back to it later, I want to create a branch from "**test works**" and try another direction, and only then decide.

I know I can create another "branch", like this:

[image: current]

but it forces me to add another branch. Is there any way I can get to the following state?

[image: final]

(where the top-of-the-tree (aka "HEAD"?) has no branch)

I prefer only Git-Extension point-and-click GUI actions, if there's a way to accomplish it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able (well, you could but it won't be of any use really) to rewind your branch and leave the latest revision un-referenced. The proper way of doing it would be to use another branch and let that represent the new direction of your development.

I would right-click the revision known by its comment "test works" and create a new branch from there.